# SolrCtl instance using JAAS option

Tags: solr

I am using Cloudera cluster and it is kerberosed with tsl and ssl enabled. I am trying to use create an instance using the --jaas option in solrctl command but it is not working.

The solrctl command I am using is below
    **solrctl --jaas  jaas-client.conf  instancedir --create testindex3      /home/myuserid/testindex3**

The jass-client.conf file is below
    **`Client {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      useKeyTab=true
      keyTab="<PATH TO KEYTAB>/username.keytab"
      storeKey=true
      useTicketCache=false
      debug=true
      principal="fully.qualified.domain.name@<YOUR-REALM";
    }`**

For the above command I am getting the error

Uploading configs from /user/myuserid/testindex3/conf to ZookeeperHost1:2181,ZookeeperHost2:2181,ZookeeperHost3:2181/solr. This may take up to a minute.
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /username.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is fully.qualified.domain.name@

**Error: can't upload configuration**

I am not sure why the instance is not created and what i am missing. Is there anything wrong in my jaas.conf file. Please advise

Note: I haven't used "user/fully.qualified.domain.name@

Comment: Any update on the reported issue. Appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: I created the solr cloud collection withouth the jaas conf file and used the jaas file duing the spark submit as below. The spark-submit worked file in client mode, but in cluder mode I am getting 401 unauthorized access. Please advise. The Spark submit command I am using is "spark-submit  --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path to > jaas-conf" --class SolrIndex <PATH to the jar>/SolrIndex.jar "

Comment: For cluster mode, I use the below spark-submit command 
spark-submit  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files "<file path>/jaas-clientkey.conf" --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<file path>/jaas-clientkey.conf" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<file path>/jaas-clientkey.conf" --class SolrIndex <file path>/SolrIndex.jar